# Create Column based on multiple columns values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

I want to generate a column `d` based on following conditions:

1. If column `a` contain any number and other two columns b, c have null value then put `a` in column `d`
2. If column `b` contain any number and other two columns a, c have null value then put `b` in column `d`
3. If column `c` contain any number and other two columns a, b have null value then put `c` in column `d`
4. If column `a` and `b` both contain any number and c column has null value then put `ab` in column `d`
5. If column `a` and `c` both contain any number and b column has null value then put `ac` in column `d`
6. If column `b` and `c` both contain any number and a column has null value then put `bc` in column `d`
7. If column `a`, `b` and `c` all contain any number then put `abc` in column `d`

Final output I want:

[image]

I have tried with the following code:

```
def func(df):
    if df['a'] >= 1:
        val = 'a'
    elif df['b']  >= 1:
        val = 'b'
    else:
        val = 'c'
    return val

df['d'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
df.head()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `x.index` to join col name which meet the condition.

```
df['d'] = df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(x.index[x >= 1]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks but in the actual dataframe, it has more columns. I want to specify the column name as well. How can I do this?

Comment: Use `df[['a', 'b']].apply(...` to specify the column you need.